# Why my variable lat is returning array out of bounds when my CSV contains 5 columns?

Tags: java

I try to work on a CVS file using Java. I achieved to do what I needed  for the first 3 columns but dataContent[3] is returning an error. 
I don't understand why cause my [CSV file available here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxJYZ.png), is 5 columns. Any idea ??

```
while ((lsLigne = br.readLine()) != null) {
    dataContent = lsLigne.split(";");

    for (i = 0; i < dataContent.length; i++) {

        cities = dataContent[0];
        insee = dataContent[1];
        lng = dataContent[2];
        lat = dataContent[3]; // line causing problems         
    }


    if (cities.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Attention nom de commune manquant");

    } else if (!cities.matches(motifLettersOnly)) {
        System.out.println("Attention nom de ville erroné : " + cities);

    } else if (insee.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("Attention l'Insee est manquant");            

    } else if(!insee.matches(motifNumbersOnly)){
        System.out.println("Attention Insee erronée : " + insee);         

    } else if(lng.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("Attention la longitude est manquante");

    } else if(!lng.matches(motifNumbersOnly)){
                    System.out.println("Attention longitude erronée " + lng);
    }
}


nom;insee;lng;lat;
OZAN;1284;4.91667;46.3833;
CORMORANCHE-SUR-SAONE;1123;4.83333;46.2333;
PLAGNE;1298;5.73333;46.1833;
TOSSIAT;1422;5.31667;46.1333;
POUILLAT;1309;5.43333;46.3333;
TORCIEU;;5.4;45.9167;
REPLONGES;1320;4.88333;Hello;
11111;1119;5.58333;46.0333;Champ sup
PERON;1288;5.93333;46.2;
RELEVANT;Hello;4.95;46.0833;
CHAVEYRIAT;1096;5.06667;46.1833;
;1431;5.35;45.9167;
MAILLAT;1228;;46.1333;
FARAMANS;1156;5.11667;;
BEON;1039;5.75;45.8333;
SAINT-BERNARD;1339;4.73723;lol;
ROSSILLON;1329;zaz;45.8333;
```

Comment: Well, did you do a `System.out.print(dataContent.toString());`?

Comment: Can you share the actual CSV file instead of a rendered table?

Comment: Do you mean a CSV file? If so why are you splitiing on a semi-colon and not a comma?

Comment: I have to say I didn't but I works for the rest without the `.toString`

Comment: You should never trust external data. Most probably there's a line that doesn't match the format you're expecting.

Comment: @mwarren cause in France with use numbers with comma and separate with ;

Comment: The loop is nonsense. Why check for `dataContent.length` when you hardcode the indexes afterwards?

Comment: Out of interest, what's the point of your `for` loop? You're doing the same thing multiple times, with the same data - and you're not using `i` within the loop at all. I'd at least simplify the code by removing that loop.

Comment: @MarvinK.Langlois Can you post the actual text contents of your csv file instead of an image?  It's important to see the actual data, and not a rendered version of that data.

Comment: I would like to catch the index of the error later to print "Data is not a number at row + i "

Comment: @Jordan I just did

Comment: @mwarren It doesn't matter what character is used as a delimiter. When a comma is present, for instance as a decimal separator which is very common in Europe, you want another delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

This loop

```
for (i = 0; i < dataContent.length; i++)
```

is completely useless, you can get rid of it.

I took a look at your CSV, you have no value for lat in the column of Faramans, which is probably why you're getting an out of bounds exception, because you are iterating through every line with

```
while ((lsLigne = br.readLine()) != null)
```

You can avoid the out of bounds exception like so, leaving values empty if they are not available in the csv.

```
while ((lsLigne = br.readLine()) != null) {
    dataContent = lsLigne.split(";");

    if (dataContent.length > 0) {
        cities = dataContent[0];
        if (dataContent.length > 1)
            insee = dataContent[1];
        if (dataContent.length > 2)
            lng = dataContent[2];
        if (dataContent.length > 3)
            lat = dataContent[3]; // line no longer causing problems         

        if (cities == null || cities.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Attention nom de commune manquant");

        } else if (!cities.matches(motifLettersOnly)) {
            System.out.println("Attention nom de ville erroné : " + cities);

        } else if (insee == null || insee.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Attention l'Insee est manquant");            

        } else if(!insee.matches(motifNumbersOnly)){
            System.out.println("Attention Insee erronée : " + insee);         

        } else if(lng == null || lng.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Attention la longitude est manquante");

        } else if(!lng.matches(motifNumbersOnly)){
            System.out.println("Attention longitude erronée " + lng);
        }
    }
}
```

There are also definitely better ways to handle this logic so you can take it from here.

If you really want to use that for loop, you can do something like this too.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataContent.length; i++) {
    switch(i) {
        case 0: cities = dataContent[i]; break;
        case 1: insee = dataContent[i]; break;
        case 2: lng = dataContent[i]; break;
        case 3: lat = dataContent[i]; break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments above, there are many aspects of code that could/should be improved, but I'll focus this answer on data validation only.
Any external to your program data should be checked/validated before being used. By `external` I mean any data that is not directly created/managed by the program. Ideally that is done at the moment the data is received as this limits the depth of the code that could be affected by invalid data. For validation to be effective/possible it is important input data format to be specified and agreed by all users of the application (in short it should be known how the data is formatted with any additional rules/exceptions).

With this information known in advance, a parser could be build to read all valid input data and to handle any error.

Back to your example, I would assume that a valid input line (a `String`) is one that:

- consist of exactly **4** elements (columns) separated by `;`
- 1st element is `cities` - a non-empty `String` consisting of `motifLettersOnly`
- 2nd element is `insee` - a non-empty `String` consisting of `motifLettersOnly`
- 3rd element is `lng` - a non-empty `String` consisting of `motifNumbersOnly`

Anything else would be considered as invalid data and should be handled as error (in this case - logging a message to `System.out`).

Here is a slightly modified version of your code (again it is **not a complete parser** as it just validates the data):

```
while ((lsLigne = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] dataContent = lsLigne.split(";");

    if (dataContent.length != 4) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input data: " + lsLigne);
        continue; // Not 4 elements --> the whole line is invalid and is skipped
    }

    String cities = dataContent[0];
    String insee = dataContent[1];
    String lng = dataContent[2];
    String lat = dataContent[3];

    // cities validation
    if (cities.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Attention nom de commune manquant");

    } else if (!cities.matches(motifLettersOnly)) {
        System.out.println("Attention nom de ville erroné : " + cities);

    }

    // insee validation
    if (insee.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Attention l'Insee est manquant");

    } else if (!insee.matches(motifNumbersOnly)) {
        System.out.println("Attention Insee erronée : " + insee);

    }

    // lng validation
    if (lng.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Attention la longitude est manquante");

    } else if (!lng.matches(motifNumbersOnly)) {
        System.out.println("Attention longitude erronée " + lng);
    }
}
```

Note that the whole line is checked first for valid number of elements - that ensures no `IndexOutOfBounds` exception for 3 or less elements, but also that there are no more than 4 elements (for example if someone deleted a line-end in the file by mistake, joining two data lines).

After that **each** element (cities, insee, lng, etc.) validation is done on itself - in your code an empty `cities` error would prevent the validation of `insee` and `lng` and that is usually not what you would want (a report of all data errors on the line).